# PHP with HTML textarea

Tags: php, html, variables, textarea

I am quite new to PHP/HTML all this kind of stuff so sorry if this is an easy question!

Is there a way to read the contents of an HTML text area and pass it into a .php file?

Or even just reading the contents of the text area into a variable would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with a basic `form`:

index.php:

```
<?php

if ($_POST) // If form was submited...
{
    $text = $_POST["mytextarea"]; // Get it into a variable
    echo "<h1>$text</h1>"; // Print it!
}

?>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="mytextarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

And this can be done whatever input element you want e.g: inputs type `text`, `password`, `checkbox`, `radio` or a `select` or even and fresh [HTML5 input type](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/).

Answer (score 3):

Give your textarea a name and post it to a PHP script with a form. The data from the textarea will be available in the $_POST['textareaName'] variable.

HTML

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="myTextarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo $_POST['myTextarea'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Post the form and can access the variable of the form with `$_POST['myObj'];`
Looking at the `$_POST` and fetching the value from the post through object name.

Here, "myObj" is an example object name.

Answer (score -1):

you need to submit the form to get the textarea value. Or you can use Jquery to get the textarea content